# How to style ordered list items only? Not unordered list items nested inside

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, html-lists

so I want to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs2Tk.png)

This is my code so far:

CSS

```
ol{
    list-style-type:decimal;
}
ol li{
    color: #9e9e9e;
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    list-style-position:inside;

}
```

HTML

```
<ol>
        <li>
            <ul>
            <li><b>Title</b></li>
            <li><p class="subtitulos"Subtitle</p></li>
            <li>Stuff 1</li> 
            <li>Stuff 2</li>
            <li>Stuff 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Instead, I get everything styled like the numbers (title,subtitle, stuff..etc)

Im making an app with ionic framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you want to accomplish, I suggest putting the big numbers in divs instead of trying to nest the lists. That way you can control the positioning. Below I created a `.num` class for the number divs. I also added `.wrap` class which has `display: table` that goes around the number divs and the lists. Then I set `display: table-cell` on `.num` and `ul` so that they display with equal height. I then set `vertical-align: middle` on `.num` so that it is centered vertically.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-cell;
}

ul li {
  color: #9e9e9e;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.wrap {
  display: table;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.num {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="num">1</div>
  <ul>
    <li><b>Title 1</b></li>
    <li>
      <p class="subtitulos">Subtitle 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>Stuff 1</li>
    <li>Stuff 2</li>
    <li>Stuff 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="num">2</div>
  <ul>
    <li><b>Title 2</b></li>
    <li>
      <p class="subtitulos">Subtitle 2</p>
    </li>
    <li>Stuff 1</li>
    <li>Stuff 2</li>
    <li>Stuff 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I forgot to add that this is an app and the lists numbers wont depend on me but the users input. There could be a million list items for all I know.

Comment: @DPF Are you generating the list from the user's input, via JavaScript maybe? If so, you just have to generate a different structure. Use CSS classes so that the styles apply to everything no matter how many there are.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier to count the numbers (1,2,3) with variables and then use for example a table or div box using flexbox in order to assume the view?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 1
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

ul li {
    color: #9e9e9e;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li><b>Title</b></li>
        <li><p class="subtitulos"Subtitle</p></li>
        <li>Stuff 1</li> 
        <li>Stuff 2</li>
        <li>Stuff 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li><b>Title</b></li>
        <li><p class="subtitulos"Subtitle</p></li>
        <li>Stuff 1</li> 
        <li>Stuff 2</li>
        <li>Stuff 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select ol direct li children, as li must be direct child of either ol or ul. It would still select nested ol li.

```
ol > li {}
```

However you should use classes and style classes instead. HTML selectors are too wide, you will encounter selector collisions.

Comment: Yeah I did that but for some reason it styles all li nested inside ul as well